# NSSortDescriptor reorders cells alphabetically after viewing detail view and returning

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've got a more or less basic Master Detail app. I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d664C98BIIY) to get familiar with `Core Data`, and now I'm trying reorder my cells on my Master TVC. Everything is working fine, including the successful reordering of my cells. However, when I dig down and view one of the detail VCs, I return to the original, alphabetized ordering. I believe it has something to do with the `NSSortDescriptor` "`sortDescriptor`" that was included in the tutorial. I am not sure how to remove it, or how to give it different characteristics. Any help is appreciated. Below is my `NSFetchedResultsController` method.

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController*) fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Top" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"topName" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

**EDIT:**
After much research over the past few days, I'm realizing it's more of an issue with my moveRowAtIndexPath method. Anyone have any suggestions or recommendations of working with Core Data and the ability to reorder cells? Also, does this require custom tableviewcell class?

Comment: What is done in your `viewDidAppear` method? It looks like something gets reset there.

Comment: @RainerSchwarze I actually am not calling the viewDidAppear method. I am however calling the viewWillAppear. Here's that code: -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

Comment: What do you mean with reorder? If you mean drag and drop cells deciding their ordering, I would like to know if you are saving changes done in the context.

Comment: @flexaddicted I am trying to allow the functionality of changing the order in which the cells of the table appear. I don't want the in alphabetical order, probably more appropriate to have them in the order in which they created the cell. I want the user to be able to decide which is most important to them. Something along the lines of canMoveRowAtIndexPath and moveRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController doesn't support move/reorder - it's a representation of the core data result set. To do what you seem to want to do, you'd have to maintain a collection at the display layer that is populated by core data/fetched results controller, and THAT is what you move/reorder. It's doable but certainly drives up your complexity.

Comment: @quellish is this the same route that most apps take when receiving user data into the app? It seems like this is something very common. Is everyone adopting this complexity or are there other options that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table view is sorted based on a name.  Given that the names are fixed, if you reorder cells 'by hand' and then return to the table view, the sorting based on the name is reestablished.

To get what you want you'll need to add a field to your Core Data model called something like `sortIndex`.  You then sort the table with a `sortDescriptor` based on `sortIndex`; you can initialize `sortIndex` to the creation order.  When the User reorders cells through the UI, you'll also change the `sortIndex` for all the impacted cells/managed-objects.  Then, since `sortIndex` is part of the Core Data model, when the User ends and restarts your App, their preferred sorting will be reestablished.

Sometimes, for modeling reasons, you don't want to include a `sortIndex` directly in some managed object.  For example, a `Person` has first and last names but not a `sortIndex` (in fact).  You can create an association, perhaps a `DisplayPreferences` managed object, with a one-to-one mapping between a `Person` and a `DisplayPreferences` and having a `sortIndex` in `DisplayPreferences`.

Comment: this is the first thing that actually makes sense to me, however, I am still very young to it all especially Core Data. I've added "sortIndex" as an attribute to my Core Data's entity "Top". I am unfamiliar with initializing to the creation order, can you explain a little more, for instance in which method, etc. Also, where/how do I update the sortIndex throughout the app where changes have been made. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: After dissecting a few github projects that also did what you described, I got it to work. Thanks so much! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

A few things you need to check here:

1. You need to actually perform the fetch the first time by calling `performFetch:` on the NSFetchedResultsController.  Either do this in the getter method or it should be done in `viewDidLoad`.
2. Have you implemented the required NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods properly?  That includes `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`, `controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:` and `controllerDidChangeContent:`.  The code is all boilerplate but you need to make sure it is there.
3. What do your UITableViewDatasource methods look like?  Make sure the sections and row counts look like this:

   ```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
       return [[[self fetchedResultsController] sections] count];
   }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
       id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
       return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
   }
   ```
4. Make sure you are using the indexPath to grab your object in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.  It should look something like this:

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCellIdentifier"];
       NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       cell.textLabel.text = rowPackage.title;

       return cell;
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you for your thorough response, but each of these things are accounted for in my code. I am reading in many places that this shouldn't be done at all in the FRC, but instead in the moveRowAtIndexPath. Not sure if this helps you to understand a little better. Thanks again.